# Is it possible to statically export a Nextjs 13 project to only one HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js13

I'm working with a 13.x.x Nextjs project. The requirement is that I have to export this project statically to only one HTML file. For example, I'm having out folder with several HTML, each for one page in the project, but I want all these page is exported into only one file index.html. Is there any way to do it?

[image: Here the out folder now]

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Lars cause I can't navigate between pages after deploy project to s3, but everything works well when I test on surge.sh or vercel. So my customer wants me to do that to see whether the problem root is out folder or not

Comment: Fixing S3 deployment issues will likely be more efficient and maintain the integrity and benefits of your Next.js project better than attempting to merge all pages into a single HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. Each page should have its own html file.